# How to check if untrusted code is safe to execute?

Tags: deno

For instance, I have a string representation of some JS function that was received from a user and should be executed on the server-side.

Is there any way to check if this code is safe to execute? By safe I mean: using only custom context and basic classes, do not try to reassign native objects, do not try to make additional network calls or infinite loops, and so on.

Previously I have used the `vm2` module of `NodeJS` for such purpose.

Comment: "do not try to make […] infinite loops" – So … you are asking whether it is possible to write a program which decides whether another program will eventually halt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to check if untrusted code is safe to execute?

You can't in any reliable way

---

But what you can do is run that code in a different context, using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) without `Deno` namespace.

```
// deno property defaults to false
const worker = new Worker(new URL("worker.js", import.meta.url).href, { type: "module", deno: false });
```

You can either pass the string to the worker and `eval/Function` inside. Or save user code to a file and call `Worker` with that file, you can add a wrapper to the user's code so you can return the output to the main process.

With `deno: false` the worker won't have access to `Deno` namespace, so the user won't be able to execute filesystem calls, start a server, read environment variables, etc.

And regarding infinite loops, add a timer in the main process and kill the `Worker` if it hasn't finished by then, using [`.terminate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate)

Regarding `fetch` Web API, to prevent network calls, you can run deno **without** `--allow-net` flag or you can limit network calls to a specific domain. `--allow-net=deno.land`

Have in mind that currently there's no way to limit the maximum memory that can be allocated by a Worker. The limits will be the same as the Deno main process.

Comment: Can you provide example without need of creating a new file on my server please?

Comment: And also what about native JS `fetch` function that isnt part of `Deno` methods but can also lead to network calls with huge data consumption to break my server. Can this happens with workers and can i control it?

Comment: It'll take me some time, so I'll do it tonight.

Comment: Cool but one last concern is do not allow untrusted code to reassign native objects cos i only want to use (if i would) workers to check for safety, as title said, and then create new function through constructor and use it further in code with custom arguments. I dont really want to create a new worker each time for this cos perfomance is very important for me.

Comment: You don't need to create a new Worker, you can send messages to an already running worker, and I suggest you don't run user code outside the Worker.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. What you are asking for is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

In fact, this part of your requirements:

> do not try to make […] infinite loops

is not just equivalent to the Halting Problem, this literally *is* the Halting Problem.

As we know, the Halting Problem is undecidable, so what you want to do is provably impossible.

Comment: Well, delegating untrusted code to independent subprocess and control his execution from main stream is pretty much solve it. Not in the way i was asking but whatever.